# Using officer in R to hyperlink to another slide within a flextable cell

Tags: r, flextable, officer

Using `officer` in `R`, I've used `ph_slidelink()` to hyperlink a text box to another slide in the presentation, and I've used `compose()` and `hyperlink_text()` to hyperlink a cell within a flextable. My question is: is there a way to combine these, and to hyperlink to another slide in the presentation within the cell of a flextable?

Here's a very simple example of code I'd like to transform:

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

ft <- data.frame(slide_number = seq(3)) %>%
  flextable() %>%
  width(width = 3)

doc <- read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide() %>%
  ph_with("Table of Contents", location = ph_location_label("Title 1")) %>%
  ph_with(ft, location = ph_location_label("Content Placeholder 2")) 

for (i in seq(3)) {
  doc <- doc %>% 
    add_slide() %>%
    ph_with(paste("Slide", i), location = ph_location_label("Title 1"))
}

print(doc, target = "~/Desktop/officer_example.pptx" )
```

...and in this case I'd like the 1/2/3 in the table of contents (here) to link to slides 1/2/3.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not possible right now (I am the maintainer of the package). I never thought about this, it's a good idea

Comment: Okay thank you!! For now I think I'll just create empty text boxes and place them over the cells in the table, and hyperlink those, as a hacky workaround. If you know of a better hacky workaround let me know :)

Comment: no sorry, feel free to open a github issue asking for this feature - it makes sure I don't forget :)

Comment: @DavidGohel any follow up on this?

Comment: @megmac No, there hasn't been any specific follow-up on this.